# Snakemake: missing file operand when using cluster

Tags: python, shell, cluster-computing, pbs, snakemake

I am deploying a snakemake workflow on a PBS cluster (PBSpro). I'm running into a problem where shell commands run on cluster nodes are failing due to missing arguments/operands to the shell command. Below is a minimal example that can reproduce the behavior I'm seeing:

```
rule all:
    input: 'foo.txt'

rule run_foo:
    output: 'foo.txt'
    shell: 'touch {output}'
```

Run from the command line as:

```
snakemake all
```

The workflow runs to completion without any errors. However, run from the command line as:

```
snakemake all --jobs 1 --cluster "qsub -l select=1:ncpus=1 -l walltime=00:05:00 -A $PROJECT -q share -j oe"
```

The workflow fails and the produces a cluster log such as this:

```
Error: Image not found
Error in job run_foo while creating output file foo.txt.
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 7 of /glade2/scratch2/jhamman/Snakefile:
Command 'touch foo.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  File "/glade2/scratch2/jhamman/Snakefile", line 7, in __rule_run_foo
  File "/glade/u/home/jhamman/anaconda/envs/storylines/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

What appears to be happening is that the arguments to the command (in this case `touch`) are not applied, despite being listed traceback.

Is there a trick to passing shell commands to a cluster via snakemake that I am missing?

Comment: Can you ssh into the node on your cluster and confirm that `touch foo.txt` works there? Also, what happens if you just run with `--cluster "qsub"`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands - On this cluster, the arguments shown above are required by qsub. Jobs are rejected without them.  Yes, `touch foo.txt` works via a direct ssh to a compute node.

Comment: Can you check what happens if you `echo` something before `touch` command? Does it produce output at least for `echo`? Fyi, I use LSF cluster and this code works as expected.

Comment: @JeeYem - Good suggestion, echoing the shell line results in an empty string. In other words, there is nothing else to be executed.

Comment: You might want to check [discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/snakemake/K9Dygz_vfck)

Comment: Have you tried option "-S /bin/bash" for qsub? This will force your shell to be bash on the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was using a fairly old version of snakemake. For some reason, conda had pinned my version. In any event, a manual upgrade to the latest stable version of snakemake seems to have resolved this issue.